# check input field value on enter press against js object value

Tags: javascript, html

My input field `<input type="text" id="barcode" placeholder="Barcode"
    onkeypress="search(this)">`

and I want to check it's value by pressing enter against a value in my js object.

```
function search(ele) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        // element.anr is the value i want to check my input against
        if (ele.value === element.anr) {
            // action that should be performed if value is equal
            document.getElementById("next").click();        
        }
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? Nothing happens when I put the correct value and hit enter (sidenote the `document.getElementById("next").click();` is showing me the next key and its values of my js object)

Comment: Did you try debugging? What does `console.log(ele.value,element.anr)` give?

Comment: Provide you `element.anr`.

Comment: seems to be working here https://jsbin.com/gigiteqesu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hey, thanks guys. For some reason it shows `ReferenceError: element is not defined`. However, I can show element.anr value in a table in my js code above

Comment: I just tested it with `ele.value` for example, get the same message `ReferenceError: element is not defined` so I guess it's not the Problem of `element.anr` value.

Answer (score 0):

just tested `element.anr as 123` and tried, its working fine

```js
function search(ele) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
    var anr="123"
        // element.anr is the value i want to check my input against
        if (ele.value == anr) {
            // action that should be performed if value is equal
            console.log(ele.value+" - "+anr);
            document.getElementById("next").click();
            
        }
    }
}

function printHi()
{
console.log("HAIIIII")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="barcode" placeholder="Barcode"
    onkeypress="search(this)">
    
    <button id="next" onclick="printHi();">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `eventListeners`,

```
const node = document.getElementsById("barcode");
node.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Do more work
    }
});
```